# Java- Draw rectangle after clicking button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

This simple code is supposed to draw rectangle after hitting button, but it doesn't work.I didn't know how to do it and the only thing came to my mind was a boolean variable trigger but it doesn't seem to work.Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
public class testing extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public JButton button;
    public boolean check;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if(check==true){
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(30, 50, 50, 50);
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        button=new JButton();

        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,20));
        button.setText("ClickMe"); 
        button.addActionListener(this);

        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
    }    

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
        check=true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        testing x=new testing();
        x.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `repaint` in your `ActionListener`. Use `paintComponent` instead of `paint` for custom painting in Swing. Also invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`

Comment: @Reimeus `JFrame` doesn't have the `paintComponent` method

Comment: Yep I know, thats why I encourage the OP to read [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and figure out the bit about the new class required (hint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call repaint inside actionPerformed.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
    check=true;
    repaint();
}
```